# Containers and wine

Tags: halacha, gentiles, grapes-wine, yayin-nesech, keilim

Is there any outer container (a frame or box, perhaps) into which an open bottle of non-mevushal wine can be placed that will shield the bottle in such a way that, if a non-Jew (or heretic) casually touches the outer container (but does not pour the wine), the wine remains halachically acceptable?

Comment: Alix, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this intriguing question! I hope you get good answers, and that you also look around the site and find other information of interest, perhaps starting with our 80+ other [tag:grapes-wine] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: If so, I'd be very wary. An open bottle of wine in a box is liable to spill, as people won't know it's open and won't handle it with due care.